# Possible to Change Embedded Resource Path Separator Character?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

I store a whole bunch of files as embedded resources within an assembly.  Calling `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames` returns things similar to the following:

```
Folder1.Resource1.cshtml
Folder1.Folder2.common.js
```

etc.

I have a class that builds a virtual directory/file system based on these names.  However, I am having an issue with resources such as:

```
Folder1.Folder2.jQuery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
```

As there is no way (unless you handle it as a special case) to know that `jquery-ui-1` and `10` and `3`, etc are not folder names, with a final resource of `min.js`.  Currently I get around this by ensuring that all my embedded resources do not contain multiple periods.  That said, is there a way to change the path separator to a different character to avoid this problem entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to get the `ResourceManager`? If so, you can use [`BaseName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.basename.aspx)

You could use the `Assembly.GetTypes()` to use the type to get to the `ResourceManager`, or you could even potentially cross reference directly against the `FullName` of the Types.